# How to handle various App states effectively with conditional navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

**Question:** When navigating to another screen ( Home Screen ) from Login, the state of Login Composable persists and when coming back( Logging out ) from the HomeScreen, the logic brings to Home Mediator for appropriate screen to render but the state of login and logout both exists with an infinite loop. **How to handle the states effectively for Login and Logout ?**

I have two View Composables, a View model to hold the state of the view and a Viewmodel event to trigger a specific function(API call for instance).

- **Login**
- **Home**

  **The flow of the example is Login -> Home, and Home (Logout Action) -> Login.**

This would require to have conditional navigation as there's an Authentication Graph and Home Graph

So I have a Home Mediator which gets a state from an authenticator. The state has LOGGED IN, LOGGED OUT and UNDETERMINED(as the state needs to have am initial Value).

There's a navigation graph setup that has two routes for instance:

```
navHost(HOME_MEDIATOR_ROUTE) {
         composable(HOME_MEDIATOR_ROUTE) {
        HomeMediator(onLoggedIn { popBackStack() })
    }
    composable(LOGIN_ROUTE) {
        LoginScreen( onLoginSuccess { navigateToLoginRoute } )
    }
    composable(HOME_ROUTE) {
        HomeScreen( onLogoutSuccess { navigateBackToLogin } )
    }
}
```

When in Login screen and Logout screen, I send an event to respective view models for an API requests and once the results are back, I set the results in a Mutable state of Login Object and Logout with State info, loading and some other boolean values. Login and Home Screens both have initial check for the login and logout and based on it, they get navigated to HomeMediator from where further appropriate navigation occurs.

**Here's the HomeMediator Snippet:**

```
@Composable
fun HomeMediator(
    homeUiState: DashboardState,
    homeUIEvent: (DashboardUIEvent) -> Unit,
    authLoginStatusStorage: AppLoginStatusStorage,
    loginState: LoginState,
    loginEvent: (AuthLoginUIEvent) -> Unit,
    onNavigateToLogin: () -> Unit,
) {
   
    // If the state was logged in already, the condition falls under LOGGED_IN and navigates to HomeScreen. But since HomeScreen has the State of Logged out, it again popsOutOfStack and lands here causing the infinite loop. 
    val authLoginStatus by authLoginStatusStorage.appLoginStatusState.collectAsState()

    when (authLoginStatus) {
        AppLoginState.LOGGED_IN -> { HomeScreen() } // Already logged in, navigate to Home 
        AppLoginState.LOGGED_OUT -> { LoginScreen() } // Logged Out, navigate to Login
        AppLoginState.LOGGED_UNDETERMINED -> { SplashScreen() } // Initial State, navigate to Splash
    }

}
```

Problem -> The authLoginStatus has the previous login state ( Logged In ) and the current Logged Out state so it becomes an infinite loop.

**Login Snippet:**

```
@Composable
fun EmployeeLoginScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    loginState: LoginState,
    authLoginUIEvent: (AuthLoginUIEvent) -> Unit,
    onNavigateToDashbaord: () -> Unit,
    authLoginStatusStorage: AppLoginStatusStorage
) { 
    
     // If Logged In, pop back stack which navigates back to HomeMediator.
    if (loginState.isLoggedIn) { 
        authLoginStatusStorage.onLoggedIn()
        onNavigateToDashbaord()
    }
    
    Other Composables ... 

}
```

When successfully logged In, the Login View Model sets the Login state sets the isLoggedIn
Login State holds info about the login state and before loading in other view, checks for the state, as it can be triggered if Login is Successful.

**Login View Model**

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepository: IAuthRepository,
    private val authLoginStatusStorage: AppLoginStatusStorage
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _logoutState = mutableStateOf(LogoutState())
    ...
}
```

**Home Screen Snippet: The root problem is occurring here.**

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    homeState: HomeState,
    homeUIEvent: (HomeUIEvent) -> Unit,
    popBackStack: () -> Unit,
    authLoginStatusStorage: AppLoginStatusStorage
) {

    // Prefetch data if requried.
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        homeUIEvent(HomeUIEvent.FetchUserData)
    }

    // If Logged out, pop back stack which navigates back to HomeMediator.
    if (homeState.isLoggedOut) { 
        authLoginStatusStorage.onLoggedOut()
        popBackStack()
    }

    Other Composables ...

}
```

When successfully logged out, the Home View Model sets the home state sets the isLoggedOut

**Home View Model Snippet:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepository: IAuthRepository,
    private val authLoginStatusStorage: AppLoginStatusStorage
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _loginState = mutableStateOf(LoginState())
    ...
}
```

Will appreciate a good explanation of the state behavior, mutable state and correctly handling the state from a Composable.

Comment: I've read it twice and still don't understand exactly the problem. I think it's too much code and domain complexity to digest it easily. I'd be happy to help, but first, try to focus on the exact issue, preferably without all of your project-specific code.

Comment: @MieszkoKoźma I've made the comment in HomeMediator code block. But here's the problem - If the state was logged in already, the condition falls under LOGGED_IN and navigates to HomeScreen. But since HomeScreen has the State of Logged out, it again popsOutOfStack and lands in HomeMediator causing the infinite loop.